# postgresql select multiple number literals for use in a subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery, literals

I'll be short.  I want a syntactically short way of checking tons of conditions in the postgres REPL.  Writing the following is a huge pain:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE specid = 1 OR specid = 3 OR specid = 7 OR ...
```

It'd be way nicer if I could do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE specid IN [0,3,5,2,7];
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE specid IN ( SELECT 0, 1, 2 );
```

But, of course that just gave me multiple columns.  Is there a way to select multiple literals as rows in one column for use as a subquery that is concise enough to be convenient in the REPL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Most likely "read–eval–print loop", i.e. `psql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE specid IN (0, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Oh dear.  I hope people looking for this answer will find it here instead of wasting their time fumbling through the docs.  Thank you, good sir.